# firebase: not found on github action deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, firebase-hosting

React app deploys fine through local cli,
though on github actions it fails with error:

```js
sh: 1: firebase: not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

package.json:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build && firebase deploy -P riplir",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume from this that you have the firebase executable on your desktop and not in the pipeline. Whilst the pipeline could be totally valid commands and configuration for firebase, it won't be able to do anything without the executable.

Try adding a pre-requisite command like:

```sh
npm init
npm install --save firebase
```

Or using an image that is guaranteed to have an up to date version of the firebase executable present.

See the [Firebase package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) for more information.